# AD user impersonation does not propagate to database with integrated security

Tags: database, active-directory, impersonation, integrated-security

I have a setup where I impersonate an AD user as described [here](http://justgeeks.blogspot.com/2007/09/impersonating-user-programmatically-in_06.html). The app connects to the (Oracle) database using integrated security, but the impersonated credentials are not propagated to the database.

Are there any known issues with impersonating AD users and accessing the database with integrated security?

Comment: Not all versions of Oracle support Windows Integrations, and it has to be turned on even when available. Are you sure Windows Integration works in your environment?

Comment: Yes, it works fine when I do not use AD impersonation.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this in Windows Web Applications where AD impersonation would not work because SQL Server would not trust the relaying party, i.e. IIS. In my example, basically IIS was telling SQL Server that the credentials provided are legitimate, but SQL Server would not trust the web server to present these credentials, some times called the double hop issue. Have you tried in [AD to trust your application/web server for delegation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739764%28WS.10%29.aspx)?

Comment: This could be it, but I will have to talk to our sysadmins to see if the fix works. I'll try it out and get back.

Comment: Trusted for Delegation is what's needed to pass the Kerberos identity off to the next "hop".